# Ionic 3 Deep link opening any link issue

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, deep-linking

I have an Ionic 3 app, I installed the ionic-plugin-deeplinks plugin and it works for what I want. When I press on a certain link in an email, it opens my app and redirects it to the necessary page. However, I have some URL on the web version of the app that has `target="_blank"` on them. Whenever I click on those, it opens the app instead of a new tab. I don't want it to open the app or ask me to open the app in those situations because it has nothing to do with the app. Just open the link in a new tab. I've tried a million things but I can't find any solution sadly...

Here's my code in config.xml.

```
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.15">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp123" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="app.myapp123.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_HOST" value=" " />
</plugin>
```

I want this link to act normally

```
<a href="https://app.myapp123.com/dont_open" target="_blank">Random URL </a>
```

but this link to ask or open the Ionic app

```
 <a href="https://app.myapp123.com/open_ionic_app" target="_blank">Random URL </a>
```

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I use [another plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme) to achieve the same:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myapp123" />
</plugin>
```

After that you can create links like "myapp123://path-to-page".
So the protocol is "myapp123" instead of https.

In that way URL's like `https://app.myapp123.com/` won't be caught anymore by your app.

More info on installation can be found here:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

One warning though: [ionic 3 deeplinking for reset password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916618/ionic-3-deeplinking-for-reset-password) : there seems to be an issue when using this technique in combination with gmail.