# ionic 3 deeplinking for reset password

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, deep-linking

I am creating a mobile application using ionic 3. I need to know the logic to implement reset password functionality. till now, i am able to send an email with reset token to the user.
I was thinking that id user clicks on the link in the email, if app is installed then it should open the application page dedicated for reset password.

So i did a little research and found that it can be done using DeepLinking ( custom url to respond) like myApp://resetPassword/{token}

Now the problem is in gmail when you send link with custom url, it removes the href option.

Can some one tell me slight information to implement this functionality and some articles to read.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just create a responsive html page that does the reset password using the old regular browser. Then the user can use the new pwd in the app.

Comment: Hi @user1027620, Actually my backend api is build in Lumen framework, which is specially for api and there should be no web based things in Lumen ( however we can add it ). so i was wondering can there be another way to tackle this.

Comment: @user280960 Just redirecting to the path in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme/issues/81 concerning this href removal in gmail.

They recommend - just as user1027620 -  to create a regular html page and use JavaScript redirection to do the trick.

I guess you will indeed need JavaScript to get the arguments (unique token...) from the url and copy them in the myApp://resetPassword url.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I have solve this by redirecting to the path in the backend after user click the link.